# Laravel 5.1 debugging error page

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am new to this framework. Sometimes it shows me errors in the page, which I have not even change. So how can I localize the exact line where I had made the mistake?

I mean is it possible to activate debugging in Laravel 5.1? and How?

Comment: People here are not my magicians Krunal, you could attach more information that helps to understand your problem.

Comment: i want to attach the picture.to explain in detail but due to my reputation i couldnt attach it

Comment: For example, you could copy the error and paste it here, it might helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please go the config folder and in app.php

change

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
```

to

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

Hope it will work for you. :)

**Note:** Remember to put it back to false when you finish your project and move it to production.

Comment: Thanks a lot. thats exactly what i want .

Comment: There is a better way to activate the debug mode. Create/edit an `.env` file and set there `APP_DEBUG=true`. See .env.example.